# How to get id from selected row using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, oop, crud

I have two pages , page one where you can view the information and on click on edit icon of row it will go to page two with the id to display the data. Page two once the data is displayed you can update the data etc.

[button click getting id in view file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyAwX.png)

[view file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPllh.png)

[edit file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07lo8.png)

Comment: What is the problem??.need more information.

Comment: Please don't post images an stackoverflow. Include the code directly into your question instead. There are a plenty reasons why screenshots aren't [welcome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get id from Url.Use this id and fill the data in edit form by ajax on  call `$( window ).load(function() {// Run code});.`

```
 var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;
  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : 
            decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
            }
        }
    };

    id = getUrlParameter('Edit');
    console.log(id);//check console
```